# Can't figure out why this loop in C stops on first float value

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I am currently working on a lab assignment for a course in C programming that I am taking. I just completed the lab, ran my code, and checked the results. Then, I went and ran the correct answer/code that is included for each lab, and I realized that the answer I'm getting with my code is incorrect.

I have compared my code with the lab's answer code several times now and cannot find any differences, yet with my code the loop only runs for the first float "prices" value instead of all of them.

Below is my code that is not working properly, and then the second piece of code is the lab's correct answer code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{


float prices[]={9.99f,7.85f,15.99f,17.25f,12.00f,16.75f};
char taxable[]={'T','T','T','F','F','T'};
float total=0;

for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
    if(taxable[i] == 'T'){

        prices[i] = prices[i] + (prices[i]*0.065);
    } else {
        prices[i] = prices[i];
    }

    total+=prices[i];

    printf("New Price: %0.2f\n", prices[i]);
    printf("Total: %0.2f\n", total);


return 0;
}
}
```

Here is the output that I get when I run my code:

```
Prices: 10.64
Total: 10.64
```

Here is the lab's correct answer code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
float prices[] = {9.99f,7.85f,15.99f,17.25f,12.00f,16.75f};
char taxable[] = {'T','T','T','F','F','T'};
float total=0;

for (int i=0;i<6;i++){
    if (taxable[i] == 'T'){
        prices[i] = prices[i] + (prices[i] * 0.065);
    } else {
        prices[i] = prices[i];
    }
    total += prices[i];
    printf("New Price: $%0.2f\n", prices[i]);
    printf("Total: $%0.2f\n", total);

}

}
```

Here is the correct output that I should be getting:

```
New Price: $10.64
Total: $10.64
New Price: $8.36
Total: $19.00
New Price: $17.03
Total: $36.03
New Price: $17.25
Total: $53.28
New Price: $12.00
Total: $65.28
New Price: $17.84
Total: $83.12
```

Comment: Your "correct answer code" includes "`prices[i] = prices[i];`"? Maybe time to change classes...

Comment: Properly indent your code and look where your `return` statement is.

Comment: What's wrong with prices[i] = prices[i] ? That's included in the lab's correct answer by the instructor.

Comment: And Nik what do you mean by "properly indent your code" ?

Comment: @user3055015 I mean that, as shown here, the indentation is borked. Look how you have two closing curly braces at the same indent level. Use whitespace and indentation to help you visualize your code. Once each block of code is indented the error should be obvious: the `return` is inside the `if`. Take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `return 0` is in the for loop block - that means the program ends after the first iteration.

You should move it out of the loop, like this:

```
    printf("Total: %0.2f\n", total);
}

return 0;
```

Instead of like this:

```
    printf("Total: %0.2f\n", total);
    return 0;
}
```

as you currently have it.